# If a program formatted my usb to 60mb, can it go back to 16gb?

Tags: formatting, usb

I had a memory stick that i attempted to install mac osx on it but the install failed and the memory stick is 60mb. Can I fix this?

Comment: Repartition the stick. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Windows 10's disk manager can repartition a memory stick.

Comment: it still keeps it at 60mb and i tried using USB Disk Format Tool 5.1 and it says F:\ in use when it isn't

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what you tried to do with the disk managed and what exactly happened?

Comment: i tried to mount a dmg onto my usb using TransMac and it made it 60mb

Comment: You can repartition it with Windows 10's disk manager.

Comment: I cant because it still keeps it at 60mb like I said earlier.

Comment: And, again, can you be a bit more precise about what you tried to do with the disk manager and exactly what happened rather than just telling me that it didn't work. You might be using the wrong tool or trying the wrong thing. What happened when you tried to repartition it with the Windows disk manager?

Comment: i right clicked the drive and pressed format and made sure its fat32 and it stayed at 60mb

Comment: I suggested you repartition the disk using the disk manager. It sounds like you tried to reformat a partition using explorer. Use the disk manager, not explorer. Select the disk, not a partition on it. And repartition it, do not format it.

Comment: ok im on disk manager how do i repartition it

Comment: Start by right-clicking on any existing partitions and deleting them. Make 100% sure you are only messing with the disk you mean to mess with!

Comment: excuse me sir, it doesnt have a partition

Comment: Then I can't imagine what was 60MB or what you formatted. Can you take some image snapshots of what the disk manager shows?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wpCR9SP.png

Comment: Is it disk 2? I see three partitions there. If it's disk 2, delete all three partitions and create a new one that uses the whole disk.

Comment: yes i delete all of those?

Comment: Yes, assuming disk 2 is the 16GB removable disk you're talking about.

Comment: i deleted one and then... http://i.imgur.com/O7dIDQb.png

Comment: Keep going, delete them all (you may need to remove the drive letter from the one that has a drive letter). Then create a new partition that covers the whole disk and assign it a drive letter.

Comment: i cant do anything to unallocated or the primary part even though i removed the letter

Comment: What goes wrong when you try? Were you able to get rid of all the partitions?

Comment: here look.. http://i.imgur.com/TRebaqq.gifv

Comment: I'm not sure why it won't let you delete the first partition. It should. Try removing and re-inserting the disk.

Comment: Its ok, I just use ease us. Thanks anyway sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to repartition the disk, using any repartitioning tool you like. On Windows, the disk manager is your best choice. Delete all existing partitions on the disk and create one partition using the full disk.